# Building Google Maps example project with Android Studio 2.2.2

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, gradle

I have just downloaded Android Studio 2.2.2 and I try to build example projects. Blank activity project builds, deploys and runs successfully on my phone.

Then I try to build Google Maps project. I obtained an API key, copied it into `google_maps_api.xml` and didn't change anything else. Then, if I press Build -> Build APK, it fails with the following messages in Gradle Console:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72500Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportPaletteV72400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42500Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2500Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAwareness980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCastFramework980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesClearcut980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGass980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesInstantapps980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlaces980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanager980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerApi980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthCommon980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthModule980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseConfig980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCrash980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessaging980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorage980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorageCommon980Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 53.036 secs
```

First I noticed "Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature" message. Maybe incremental compilation is the reason of the failure? If so, how can I disable it? I didn't find anything about it in `build.gradle` and other gradle-related files.

And if incremental build is not the reason, then what is it and how to fix it? This:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
    > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

looks like a gradle internal error. Am I right? Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: can you post your gradle file ?

Comment: @14bce109 I added the file to my question.

Comment: Please post your solution if solved. I am waiting more than 10 days to know it.

Comment: @SulungNugroho See the link in MarcinOrlowski's accepted answer, it solved my problem. Shortly, if your `minSdkVersion` is 21 or higher, add `multiDexEnabled true` to a specific place in your `build.gradle` file. In another case some additional steps should be taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

You must enable multidex for your project as total number of methods in your build exceeds 65536. See [Configure Apps with Over 64K Methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)